# images doesn't fit to the carousel in bootstrap 4

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a carousel with images. But the images are shown too zoomed in.

Here is my html code:

```
<header>
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <!-- Slide One - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
        <div class="carousel-item active" style="background-image: url(/images/holz_5.jpg)">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h3>First Slide</h3>
            <p>This is a description for the first slide.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Slide Two - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
        <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url(/images/holz_6.jpg)">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h3>Second Slide</h3>
            <p>This is a description for the second slide.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Slide Three - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
        <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url(/images/holz_4.jpg)">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h3>Third Slide</h3>
            <p>This is a description for the third slide.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </header>
```

This is my css code:

```
.carousel-item {
  height: 65vh;
  min-height: 300px;
  background: no-repeat center center scroll;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  object-fit: cover !important;
}
```

This is how it lookes like:

[image: zoomed]

This is the original image:

[image: original]

Why is it so zoomed in the picture? I want that it keeps the original size, that it fits to the carousel.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [stretched image in carousel bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55087147/stretched-image-in-carousel-bootstrap)

Comment: doesnt help :/..

Comment: try to use instead of  background-size: cover; use contain

Answer (score 1):

You can compare your code with this. The pictures are zooming perfectly here.

Update: Remove the `img` style tag from the CSS code to avoid global styling for all single images.

```css
.carousel-item {
  background: no-repeat center center scroll;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  object-fit: cover !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h3>Third Slide</h3>
        <p>This is a description for the third slide.</p>
      </div>
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/8h5Xz.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h3>Third Slide</h3>
        <p>This is a description for the third slide.</p>
      </div>
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/8h5Xz.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h3>Third Slide</h3>
        <p>This is a description for the third slide.</p>
      </div>
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/8h5Xz.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: idk why but this doesn't help. What is going on man :/ tried so many times

Comment: maybe there is in my entire css something wrong? I share it down.

Comment: @Behar, I have updated my answer. Be aware of global styling tags like `img` in your CSS code, it can cause confusion and unwanted struggles. Hope, this is helpful.

Comment: Can you be more specific by " images are stretched"? Please. Your question was about that one specific image that you have attached to your question, which doesn't display correctly. Is my answer meet with your requirements by your question?

Answer (score 0):

This is my whole css: Is here maybe something overriting?

```
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.15;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

.carousel-item {
  height: 65vh;
  min-height: 300px;
  background: no-repeat center center scroll;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  object-fit: cover !important;
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.2;
  color: inherit;
}

.row {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}

.row img {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
}

.navbar-brand img {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
}

.border-top {
  border-top: 1px solid #dee2e6 !important;
}

footer {
  display: block;
}

.featurette-divider {
  margin: 5rem 0; /* Space out the Bootstrap <hr> more */
}

.featurette-heading {
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: -0.05rem;
}

@media (min-width: 40em) {
  /* Bump up size of carousel content */
  .carousel-caption p {
    margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    line-height: 1.4;
  }

  .featurette-heading {
    font-size: 50px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 62em) {
  .featurette-heading {
    margin-top: 7rem;
  }
}

.marketing h2 {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.p-2 {
  padding: 0.5rem !important;
  padding-top: 0.5rem !important;
  padding-right: 0.5rem !important;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem !important;
  padding-left: 0.5rem !important;
}

#testimonia {
  background: rgba(228, 136, 31, 0.8);
  padding: 30px 0 30px 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 40px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: -0.05rem;
}

#testimonia p {
  font-size: 25px;
}

.navbar-brand {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
}

img {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px; 
}

hr {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 0;
  overflow: visible;
}

footer {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

#btn1 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.modal-header {
  background: #e4881f;
}
.full-screen {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

a {
  color: #e4881f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any issue with the carousel display. You need to decide how you want to display the image in the carousel.

There are 2 options:

**1) Don't constrain the carousel height.**

If you don't constrain the carousel height, the entire image will be visible. But the height will be very large on large screens. So, at some point its better to constrain the height of the carousel.

**2) Constrain the carousel height.**

As I seen in your code, you have constrained the height to `65vh`. When you constrain the carousel item height the image can be displayed in either

- `cover` mode - Image fills the container, but may be cropped if aspect ratio is different.
- `contain` mode - Image will not be cropped, entire image is displayed. But you may have blank areas either horizontally or vertically inside the container depending on the aspect ratio.

As I see in your code, you have used `background-size: cover`, so the image is cropped vertically to fill the container area.

For more understanding, you can visit below post on stackoverflow for how the images are positioned in `cover` or `contain` modes:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27941378/1266447

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `background-position: 50% 50%;`

Then your image is centered.

Here is all mine css code:

```
.carousel-item img {
    max-height: 80vh;
    min-height: 350px;
    background: no-repeat center center scroll;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    object-fit: cover !important;

    background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```